# Norm of adjoint proof check

Tags: functional-analysis

Let ${\cal H},{\cal K}$ be Hilbert spaces. Let $T\in B({\cal H},{\cal K})$. If ${\cal H}={\cal K}$, I know that $||T||=||T^*||$. So I was wondering if the same is true when ${\cal H}$ is not necessarily ${\cal K}$.

**attempt of proof**

If $T=0$, then equality holds. Assume $T\neq 0$. Observe: $$||T^*k||^2=\langle T^*k,T^*k\rangle=\langle TT^*k,k\rangle\leq ||TT^*||\cdot ||k||^2$$ for all $k\in {\cal K}$. Then
$$||T^*||^2\leq ||TT^*||\leq ||T||\cdot||T^*||.$$
Cancelling $||T^*||$, we get $||T^*||\leq ||T||$. By a symmetric argument, $||T||\leq ||T^*||$.

Comment: Yes, it seems ok to me.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Berci you should make that an answer.

Comment: Actually, $\|TT^*\|=\|T\|^2$ would follow, and that made me uncertain, since I don't remember such a general result. Nevertheless the proof still seems valid.

Comment: @Berci, that's one of my concerns as well that's why I asked.

Comment: @Berci, another way: Consider $S=\begin{bmatrix} 0& 0\\T& 0\end{bmatrix}\in B({\cal H}\oplus {\cal K})$. Then $||T||=||S||=||S^*||=||T^*||$.